# Team foundation server reports using analysis service

Tags: tfs, olap, analysis, tfs-reports

We faced to problem with building reports using tfs analysis serveces.

We are connecting to analysis service from excel and trying to make some filters. E.g. changed date and Changed By. Changed date filter have all empy values in its list. It is the first, biggest problem.

The second problem is in users list. One part of users in list presented by name and another part - by SID.

I found that table dbo.DimPerson in tfs_Warehouse database have values that i see in report. And Table dbo.DimDate have alll values = NULL.

Did anybody solved a problem like this? Or where i could find a solution?

Comment: is the TFS server ever moved (from a workgroup to a domain or from a domain to a workgroup, or across domains in Active Directory, or change the domain)?

Comment: No, server did not movedd. But recently we had a global AD accounts renaming.

Comment: What do you mean by AD accounts renaming? Did you just change the AD users' display name? Or also made other changes in AD?

Comment: As our system administrators said, they changed only accounts attributes.

Comment: if only the accounts attributes changed, TFS is able to sync the changes. Can you give me screenshot shows how you define the pivot table report? And also the result of the  dbo.DimPerson table?

Comment: @Vicky-MSFT Added a comment with a screenshots to the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that the Tfs_Warehouse database isn't refreshed with the latest data. You can refresh it manually or create a totally new one. Please check my reply in this link for the details: [How can one build the TFS cube from scratch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32697184/how-can-one-build-the-tfs-cube-from-scratch)

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it asap!

Comment: I rebuilt the database. and now tables are filling with data. Now data are the same as they was...maybe it will be better wheni it ends.

Comment: @AlexeySoloviev, so the dbo.DimDate table still have all data shows 'null'? And dbo.DimPerson table has SIDs shown in the ‘Name’ column?

Comment: Lets continue in this thread. here are screeenshots of pivot table in excel, DimDate And DimPerson table: [Defining pivot report table](http://i.imgur.com/sgGtP5w.png),  [Data in excel](http://i.imgur.com/TGmTS2B.png), [Filter in excel](http://i.imgur.com/TQOXpLi.png), [DimPerson](http://i.imgur.com/s2UjsaG.png), [DimDate](http://i.imgur.com/v66Wb4N.png)

Comment: After deleting and recreating of Warehouse and Analysis Databases they where filled with same data as before. DimDate is still filled with NULL. DimPerson - as at screenshots above.

Comment: @AlexeySoloviev, 1). from the 'DimPerson' screenshot you provided, it looks like that the TFS server was migrated (from one domain to another). Please run the "TFSConfig Identities" command to check whether there are different SIDs: (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253054(v=vs.120).aspx)  2). For the 'DimDate' table, do all rows contain Null values? Or just old date (DateTime is 2007 or 2012) has Null values?

Comment: yes, all rows contains NULLs. More than that. No one row contain something without NULL. Ok, i will run TFSConfig Identities and write the result here

Comment: Our Tfs was not ever migrated. I ran TFSConfig identities. 2590 security identifier(s) (SIDs) were found stored in Team Foundation Server.
Of these, 1456 were found in Windows. 2 had differing SIDs. Obly 2 Different SIDs

Comment: also we updated sql server to 2014. But all actions from above did not helped